# How to partially hide content in beamer latex?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I tried all overlay options like hide, uncover, visible but didn't get solution.
I don't know how to partially hide the content that will display in next slide.
Here is the example what I really want to do. In which the bullet 2 content will display in next slide but partially hide or a shadow in current slide.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this effect using `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` or with `\setbeamercovered{transparent=...}`  and a value of your choice. (0 = "totally transparent", 100 = "totally opaque")

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item first item 
\pause
\item second item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could also mention `\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item first item 
\item second item
\end{itemize}`. Then you do not need a `\pause`.

Comment: Thanks. It works. :)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks. I am using <+-> in place of pause

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the command `\pause` in an `itemize` or `enumerate` environment. This creates two (or more) PDF slides and when the next slide is viewed, the next line (in your case bullet point 2, then 3) appears normal and not greyed-out anymore.

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Line 1 \pause
\item Line 2 \pause
\item Line 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want this gray color on subsequent slide i.e. on slide 2 and 3.